# How to parse a string time '16-AUG-22 01.50.20' to datetime bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I parse a following string timestamp to timestamp from BigQuery: `"16-AUG-22 01.50.20.000000 PM"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below as an example

```
select parse_timestamp('%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%E*S %p', "16-AUG-22 01.50.20.000000 PM")
```

with output

[image]